# Reason for serial linked list implementation takes more time than a linked list implementation with mutex using one thread?

Tags: c, linked-list, pthreads

To investigate the performance gain using more threads I used a linked list implementation and did a number of random operations serially and using threads with mutex.

My linked list functions are in `utils.c` file and it is as follows.
(Commonly used `average` and `standardDeviation` functions are also in this file).

```c
#include <math.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

int member(int value, struct node *head) {
    struct node *current;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL && current->val < value)
        current = current->next;

    if (current == NULL || current->val > value) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int insert(int value, struct node **headp) {
    struct node *current = *headp;
    struct node *previous = NULL;
    struct node *temp;

    while (current != NULL && current->val < value) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current == NULL || current->val > value) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->val = value;
        temp->next = current;
        if (previous == NULL) {
            *headp = temp;
        } else {
            previous->next = temp;
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int delete(int value, struct node **headp) {
    struct node *current = *headp;
    struct node *previous = NULL;

    while (current != NULL && current->val < value) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current != NULL && current->val == value) {
        if (previous == NULL) {
            *headp = current->next;
            free(current);
        } else {
            previous->next = current->next;
            free(current);
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


void clearMemory(struct node **headp) {
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;

    current = *headp;
    next = current->next;
    while (next != NULL) {
        free(current);
        current = next;
        next = current->next;
    }
    free(current);
    *headp = NULL;
}

double average(const double arr[], int length) {
    if (length <= 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum / length;
}

double standardDeviation(const double arr[], int length) {
    if (length <= 1) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    double mean = average(arr, length);
    double sumSquaredDiff = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        double diff = arr[i] - mean;
        sumSquaredDiff += diff * diff;
    }

    double variance = sumSquaredDiff / (length - 1);
    return sqrt(variance);
}
```

The code for doing the operations serially is as follows. Let's call it as **A**.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "utils.c"

const int MAX_KEY = 65536;

int iterations = 1000; // number of samples need to provide 95% confidence level
int n = 1000;    // number of elements initially in linked list
int m = 10000;    // number of random operations count

float m_member = 0.99;    // fraction of member operations from m
float m_insert = 0.005;    // fraction of insert operations from m
float m_delete = 0.005;    // fraction of delete operations from m

int operation;
double start_time, finish_time, time_elapsed;

int main(void) {
    double *time_arr = (double *) malloc(iterations * sizeof(double));
    for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
        struct node *head = NULL;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            int r = rand() % MAX_KEY;
            if (insert(r, &head)) {
                i++;
            }
        }

        int member_count = m * m_member;
        int insert_count = m * m_insert;
        int delete_count = m * m_delete;

        start_time = clock();
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            operation = rand() % 3; // random number 0, 1, 2
            int r = rand() % MAX_KEY;
            if (operation == 0 && member_count > 0) {
                member(r, head);
                member_count--;
            } else if (operation == 1 && insert_count > 0) {
                insert(r, &head);
                insert_count--;
            } else if (operation == 2 && delete_count > 0) {
                delete(r, &head);
                delete_count--;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }
        finish_time = clock();
        time_elapsed = (finish_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time elapsed\t %i: %f\n", j, time_elapsed);

        time_arr[j] = time_elapsed;
        clearMemory(&head);
    }

    double avg = average(time_arr, iterations);
    double std = standardDeviation(time_arr, iterations);
    printf("Average : %f\nStandard Deviation: %f\n", avg, std);

    return 0;
}
```

And implementation with pthreads is as follows. Let's call it as **B**. Here, I have used thread count as one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "utils.c"

const int MAX_KEY = 65536;

struct thread_data {
    int i; // thread number
    int member_count;   // number of member operations in thread
    int insert_count;   // number of insert operations in thread
    int delete_count;   // number of delete operations in thread
};

struct node *head;

const int iterations = 1000; // number of samples need to provide 95% confidence level
const int n = 1000;         // number of elements initially in linked list
const int m = 10000;        // number of random operations count

const float m_member = 0.99;    // fraction of member operations from m
const float m_insert = 0.005;    // fraction of insert operations from m
const float m_delete = 0.005;    // fraction of delete operations from m

int thread_count = 1;    // number of threads

double start_time, finish_time, time_elapsed;

int member_count, insert_count, delete_count;
int member_count_per_thread, insert_count_per_thread, delete_count_per_thread;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *threadFunction(void *rank);

int main() {
    double *time_arr = (double *) malloc(iterations * sizeof(double));
    for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
        head = NULL;
        member_count = m_member * m;
        insert_count = m_insert * m;
        delete_count = m_delete * m;

        member_count_per_thread = member_count/thread_count;
        insert_count_per_thread = insert_count/thread_count;
        delete_count_per_thread = delete_count/thread_count;

        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            int r = rand() % 65536;
            if (insert(r, &head)) {
                i++;
            }
        }

        pthread_t *thread_handles;

        thread_handles = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(pthread_t));
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

        start_time = clock();
        struct thread_data **data_arr = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(struct thread_data *));
        for (i = 0; i < thread_count; i++){
            struct thread_data* data = malloc(sizeof(struct thread_data));
            data->i = i;
            if (i == thread_count -1){
                // Remaining operations are allocated to the last thread.
                // Can have few more operations than other threads if the number of operations is not divisible.
                data->member_count = member_count;
                data->insert_count = insert_count;
                data->delete_count = delete_count;
            } else {
                member_count -= member_count_per_thread;
                data->member_count = member_count_per_thread;
                insert_count -= insert_count_per_thread;
                data->insert_count = insert_count_per_thread;
                delete_count -= delete_count_per_thread;
                data->delete_count = delete_count_per_thread;
            }

//            printf("Allocated number of operations [Thread %i]\nMember : %i\nInsert : %i\nDelete : %i\n",
//                   data->i, data->member_count, data->insert_count, data->delete_count);
            data_arr[i] = data;
            pthread_create(&thread_handles[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void *) data_arr[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
            pthread_join(thread_handles[i], NULL);

        finish_time = clock();
        time_elapsed = (finish_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time elapsed\t %i: %f\n", j, time_elapsed);

        time_arr[j] = time_elapsed;

        clearMemory(&head);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        free(thread_handles);
    }

    double avg = average(time_arr, iterations);
    double std = standardDeviation(time_arr, iterations);
    printf("Average : %f\nStandard Deviation: %f\n", avg, std);

    free(time_arr);
    return 0;
}

void *threadFunction(void *data) {
    int i, val;

    struct thread_data* my_data = data;
    int my_member = my_data->member_count;
    int my_insert = my_data->insert_count;
    int my_delete = my_data->delete_count;

    for (i = 0; i < my_member + my_insert + my_delete; i++) {
        float operation = rand()%3;
        val = rand() % MAX_KEY;

        if (operation == 0 && my_member > 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            member(val, head);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            my_member--;
        } else if (operation == 1 && my_insert > 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            insert(val, &head);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            my_insert--;
        } else if (operation == 2 && my_delete > 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            delete(val, &head);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            my_delete--;
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I get the average time in **A** as `0.009037` and **B** as `0.005497`. I executed these programs again and again But ended up with similar results.
But, How is that possible? Doesn't the mutex add an additional overhead?.

Edit:
I'm using `gcc` compiler with compiler options `-lm`, `-pthread`(only for the program **B**).

Comment: OT: Why all the global variables?

Comment: As for your problem, I'm not sure what your problem actually is? I assume you want to add parallelism to make the program "quicker", and then you wonder why the parallel program is quicker? That's kind of the point of trying to use threads for expensive operations.

Comment: Is this yet another "I didn't enable optimizations, why isn't my code optimized?" question? Because they are really, really tiresome... Please post which compiler and compiler options you used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
 No. my problem is even without even using 2 or more threads, how did the program run `quicker`. I only use one thread here.

Comment: @Lundin No this is not a "I didn't enable optimizations, why isn't my code optimized?" kind of question. Just wondering program with one `pthread` is faster than the serial program. (Logically it shouldn't be)

Comment: Have you compared the number of actual operations that take place? I notice that here: `for (i = 0; i < my_member + my_insert + my_delete; i++) {` you are incrementing `i`, but you are also decrementing the three `my_` members in the body.

Comment: @MohamedIshad If you haven't enabled optimizations then anything can happen performance-wise. Benchmarking non-optimized code is senseless. Now go compile with `-O3` and see.

Comment: Aside: Your `clearMemory()` function will crash if `*headp` is `NULL` (i.e. if the list is empty). It should be something like `current = *headp;` `while (current) {` `next = current->next;` `free(current);` `current = next;` `}` `*headp = NULL;`.

Comment: @MohamedIshad, in program A you are using a single thread, in B u are using multiple threads, so in case B, you program will run on multi cores, as much core or processors u have in ur machine, so i think it's natural for B to take a shorter execute time than A. even if the pthread will call other functions but that still can be the case

Comment: Have you tried seeding the random number generator (`srand()` in both versions) with the same seed? It's conceivable the threaded version sequences operations (or generates numbers) that reduce the (expensive) calls to `malloc()`...

Comment: You are using `clock()` to time iterations of the program.  There are at least two issues with this: (1) it measures CPU time, not wall time, so the time one of your threads spends waiting for the mutex is not included in the measurement.  (2) at least on my test machine, its resolution is too coarse for your workload -- I'm seeing most of the test runs take either 0 or 1 tick of that clock.

Comment: "*Doesn't the mutex add an additional overhead?*" -- on Linux, when the mutex is uncontested, not very much.